# Devolver lista de cadenas con palabras que contengan el carácter "a" o el "o" , pero no los dos simultáneamente

Tags: python

Quiero que solo me agregue palabras que tengan los caracteres 'a' o que tengan solo 'o', pero no que tengan las dos caracteres en la misma palabra.

```
art_super = ['lampara', 'quick', 'cloro', 'jabon']
lista3 = []
for x in art_super:
    if 'a' in x or 'o' in x:
            lista3.append(x)
    else:
        if 'a' in x or 'o' in x:
            lista3.append(x) 
print(lista3)
```

Esto imprime: `['lampara', 'cloro', 'jabon']`

Pero no quiero que aparezca jabon porque estan las dos caracteres 'a' y 'o'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```
def filtrar(lista):
    resultado = []
    for nombre in lista:
        if ('a' in nombre and 'o' not in nombre) or \
            ('a' not in nombre and 'o' in nombre):
            resultado.append(nombre)
    return resultado
```

Esta función recibe una lista de palabras y las examina una por una.

Por cada palabra se pregunta si aparece una letra y no la otra

```
'a' in nombre and 'o' not in nombre
```

o viceversa

```
'a' not in nombre and 'o' in nombre
```

Las palabras que pasan la prueba son agregadas a la lista de salida.

**Demo**

```
art_super = ['lampara', 'quick', 'cloro', 'jabon']

def filtrar(lista):
    resultado = []
    for nombre in lista:
        if ('a' in nombre and 'o' not in nombre) or \
            ('a' not in nombre and 'o' in nombre):
            resultado.append(nombre)
    return resultadoa

print(filtrar(art_super))
```

produce:

```
['lampara', 'cloro']

Process finished with exit code 0
```